# How to shrink outest QWidget/top-level window if there is space available?

Tags: python, qt-designer, pyside2

Shown is the simple layout with QWidget and two tableWidgets that are both `setHidden(True)` if the button is pressed.

[image]

How do i reflow the outest/main/QWidget so that there is no blank space. The only item left is the Fixed vertical size pushbutton. all other space should be shrunken down so that only the button is left without the blank space in the QWidget. Bad result is:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the height using the sizeHint a moment after pressing the button:

```py
self.tableWidget.hide()   # or setHidden(True)
self.tableWidget_2.hide() # or setHidden(True)
QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, lambda: self.resize(self.width(), self.sizeHint().height()))
```

Comment: nice, can you please add why only with `QtCore.QTimer.singleShot` ? `adjustSize()` does not work too. I have to use a timer + resize. but why?

Comment: @qrtLs Although you use hide() does not imply that the widget is hidden at that moment since that task is done asynchronously, that is, an instant after finishing the synchronous part, so the sizeHint() is only updated at that time, so QTimer::singleShot() is used to resize an instant after the widget is hidden.